# Autofac decorator + delegate factory

Tags: c#, autofac

I am trying to use a decorator in Autofac with a delegate factory but I can't seem to get it to resolve the parameters.

```
public interface IFoo
{ }

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public Foo(string bar)
    { ... }
}

public class DecoratedFoo : IFoo
{
    public DecoratedFoo(IFoo decorated)
    { ... }
}
```

I would like to inject into a service like so:

```
public SomeService(Func<string, IFoo> factory)
{
    // I would expect IFoo to be a DecoratedFoo here
    IFoo foo = factory("hello");
}
```

I have registered components like so:

```
builder.RegisterType<Foo>()
    .Named<IFoo>("foo")
    .UsingConstructor(typeof(string));

builder.RegisterDecorator<IFoo>(
    (ctx, inner) => new DecoratedFoo(inner),
    fromKey: "foo");
```

I get an error saying it cannot resolve my parameter bar. This is a simplified example but I won't know what the value of bar is (hence using the factory).

Is there any way to accomplish what I'm doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `RegisterDecorator` - it will not propagate string parameter you pass to your factory deeper to your `Foo` constructor. Here is an open [issue](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/824) about that. So on this line

```
IFoo foo = factory("hello");
```

It will throw exception (as you observe) because it will try to find parameterless constructor of `Foo` and there is none.

To fix, you can remove your `RegisterDecorator` and instead do that manually:

```
builder.RegisterType<Foo>()
    .Named<IFoo>("foo");            
builder.Register((cnt, parameters) => 
    new DecoratedFoo(cnt.ResolveNamed<IFoo>("foo", parameters))).As<IFoo>();
```

Almost the same amount of code, but works as expected, because you manually propagate parameters.